# IN TextMate I can't create partials with Rails tmbundle

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, textmatebundles, textmate2

```
/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/ui.rb:355:in `to_plist': An object in the argument tree could not be converted (ArgumentError)
from /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/ui.rb:355:in `request_string_core'
from /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/ui.rb:193:in `request_string'
from /Users/pma/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Ruby on Rails.tmbundle/Support/bin/create_partial_from_selection.rb:23:in `<main>'
```

I installed the RoR bundle from: https://github.com/drnic/ruby-on-rails-tmbundle.git

Using rvm.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you using Ruby 1.9? The osx-plist.bundle in Textmate doesn't work with Ruby 1.9. To fix it, you can update it [as described by Loren Segal](http://gnuu.org/2009/05/25/getting-gittmbundle-working-with-ruby19/). I've changed them around slightly to build wherever you want and make the support directory:

```
$ git clone git://github.com/kballard/osx-plist.git
$ cd osx-plist/ext/plist
$ ruby extconf.rb && make
$ mkdir -p "$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Support/lib/osx"
$ cp plist.bundle "$_"
```

Comment: by the way, this is not necessary with ruby 1.9.3. The original plist.bundle works again in 1.9.3

Comment: Worked for me with "/Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx" as a target directory.

Comment: $HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Support/lib/osx did not work and neither $HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/lib/osx BUT worked for me as well with /Applications/TextMate.app/Contents/SharedSupport/Support/lib/osx

Answer (score 4):

In case you are using Textmate2 and encounter the same error as above(related to plist bundle) use the same fix as mentioned in the answer above, https://stackoverflow.com/a/7029278/206814 only the target directory is not

```
"$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Support/lib/osx"
```

but should be

```
"$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/lib/osx"
```

Overwrite the plist.bundle in this directory, then you should stop seeing errors that happen cause you are using Ruby 1.9.