# Trying to create partial from selection in Textmate 2 throws error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, textmate, textmate2

I'm getting the following error when trying to create a partial from a selection - `Ctrl + Shift + H`. Any idea what could be causing it / how to fix it?

```
/Users/harry/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/lib/ui.rb:371:in `to_plist': An object in the argument tree could not be converted (ArgumentError)
    from /Users/harry/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/lib/ui.rb:371:in `request_string_core'
    from /Users/harry/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/lib/ui.rb:209:in `request_string'
    from /Users/harry/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Ruby on Rails.tmbundle/Support/bin/create_partial_from_selection.rb:24:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6869463/in-textmate-i-cant-create-partials-with-rails-tmbundle) fix the problem.

```
$ git clone git://github.com/kballard/osx-plist.git
$ cd osx-plist/ext/plist
$ ruby extconf.rb && make
$ mkdir -p "$HOME/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Managed/Bundles/Bundle Support.tmbundle/Support/shared/lib/osx"
$ cp plist.bundle "$_"
```